# Converting Async Response to Standard Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine your React app gets a response like this:

```
email_address
first_name
last_name
```

What's a best practice way to convert these fields to something more common in Javascript:

```
emailAddress
firstName
lastName
```

Also keeping mind that there could be nested structures.

I've typically done this immediately when the response is received.

My colleagues seem to think it's fine to keep the snake_case syntax persist through the app.

Comment: Wait, do you want just the names changed, or do you actually want the data as an Object with the names changed?
Because if it's the second one, we would probably need to know how the data is coming / being stored

Answer (score 1):

There may be some edge cases that fail, I could not find anything on github that would do the trick but if you have any errors then please let me know.

It is assuming you only pass object literals to it, maybe you can write some tests and tell me if anything fails:

```js
const snakeToCamel = snakeCased => {
  // Use a regular expression to find the underscores + the next letter
  return snakeCased.replace(/(_\w)/g, function(match) {
    // Convert to upper case and ignore the first char (=the underscore)
    return match.toUpperCase().substr(1);
  });
};

const toCamel = object => {
  if (Array.isArray(object)) {
    return object.map(toCamel);
  }
  if (typeof object === 'object' && object !== null) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce(
      (result, [key, value]) => {
        result[snakeToCamel(key)] = toCamel(value);
        return result;
      },
      {}
    );
  }
  return object;
};
console.log(
  toCamel({
    arra_of_things: [
      { thing_one: null },
      { two: { sub_item: 22 } },
    ],
    sub_one: {
      sub_two: {
        sub_three: {
          sub_four: {
            sub_four_value: 22,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
);
```